# Material-ui 4.9.5 TextField attribute "required" not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple TextField wth 'required' attribute. It generated 'required=""' in the html 'input' element, and hence does not trigger the required error message(I believe that is the intended mechanism for the TextField 'required' attribute). Please see the code below and the codesandbox

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
   return (

   <div className="App">
       <TextField required label="LoftyPine" />
       <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => {}}>
       Validate
      </Button>
   </div>

   );
}
```

[Same](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-glade-21v9r)
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-glade-21v9r?file=/src/App.js:0-303)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to trigger the browser's default required error message, the `TextField` needs to be in a form, and you need to trigger the validation. There are several ways to trigger the validation such as clicking a button with `type="submit"` or calling [reportValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) on the form.

Here is an example showing calling `reportValidity`:

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const formRef = React.useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form ref={formRef}>
        <TextField required label="LoftyPine" />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          onClick={() => formRef.current.reportValidity()}
        >
          Validate
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Required TextField]

Comment: It works , but I think that was not the way it was intended. The generated html element, as seen in the devtool inspector, DOES generate an HTML **bold**'input'**bold** element WITH  'required=""' ,  which in plain html also does not work, unless it is JUST **bold'required'bold** without the ="".                                                                                                                                 The generated elemnent is : **bold**<input aria-invalid="false" required="" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input" value="">**bold**

Comment: Material-UI does no such translation. `required` is added as a boolean attribute. When I look at this through dev tools, I don't see anything different about the `required` attribute than in a plain html page (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/2gdycven/).

Comment: You are right, it needs an enclosing html <form> element, and Material FormControl does not really do it. Wonder why they even had the "required" attribute if the DOM ref hack you presented bypassed the required, sort of - Big Thank You! I learnt a lot

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by “bypassed the required”. The only thing that Material-UI does with the `required` attribute is put an asterisk on the label and pass the attribute through to the `<input>` element. It’s up to you to perform whatever validation you want.

Comment: One would imagine, the Material-ui FormControl and Input would decorate a TextField, to mirror the html architecture.  The Material-ui FormControl doc says "Provides context such as filled/focused/error/**bold**required**bold** for form inputs. Relying on the context provides high flexibility and ensures that the state always stays consistent across the children of the FormControl" And for TextField: "The TextField wrapper component is a complete form control including a label, input and help text." which seems odd, if it's a complete "form control" That is not what they seems to do.

Comment: The `TextField` maintains **styling** consistency between the label, input, and helper text. It doesn't control validation logic. You specify `error` prop as `true` to reflect an error state, based on your own validation logic (which there are dozens of different approaches for implementing) and that error styling is reflected appropriately throughout the form control. The focused and filled states impact the label and styling of the input.

Comment: In html, an enclosing form with embedded inputs coordinates the styling/error states between the inputs. But Material seems to be not very consistent - the `disable` `autofocus` pass imperative state, not just styling,  to html input, but not `required`, granted it is dependent on `form` and `button`, I expected it to, at least after wrapping it in parents FormControl/Input. The document is msileading, the `FormControl` does not really create   a `form` html.

Comment: I'm new to Material. Thanks for clarifying/clearing my understanding/expectations of what Material does, does not do. I wish though that some touches/feautures to the product would be more helpful, as the line between styling and state mapping to html is not very crisp, as in the difference between  `autofocus/disabled` state AND styling, and `required` which is dependent on button events/state of another peer component orchestrated in html by `form`. Material does have a FormControl which is more container than styling, and could be used to coordinate state in it's components like html does.

Comment: running this on chrome Version 110.0.5481.77 (Official Build) (x86_64) gives validation error twice

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ryan for pointing the way. There is another variation without mixing any html like `form` , by using the `inputRef` prop of the `TextField` component, which creates? and passes a ref to the `input` element. If we have multiple `TextField` s, the con is you have to `reportValidity` on each element, but the pro is you have more control on sequence of validation and other input level functions.

```
`import React from "react";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {

  let myRef = {}
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField required inputRef={myRef} label="LoftyPine" />
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => {myRef.current.reportValidity()}}>
        Validate
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}`
```

[WIthoutHtmlForm](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-night-kfgpe?file=/src/App.js)